# unpacking video par files where first file is for example .avi

Tags: video

Many video files are available via usenet for download as multi-part collections where the first file is often an avi.001 or mp4.001 file with other files numbered in sequence and also par repair files.

This method of file-splitting using QuickPar is usually (in my limited experience) used for individual tv episodes for upload just after broadcast.

In Windows QuickPar will treat the collection as a repair and the numbered files will be joined into the complete video file.

PyPar2 doesn't appear to deal with these. Is there any other gui available that does?

I have just used WINE to successfully install QuickPar in Ubuntu to make the repair and join. This gets me past the problem for now but only because I have reverted one pc to Ubuntu 16.4 to be able to install WINE. The newer releases won't let me run 'must have' softwares like WINE, a working get_iplayer, dukto, inaudible, avidemux etc and when 18.4 arrives 16.4 will have to go. I see now 18.4 arrived a few hours ago...

Comment: Your usenet client will not join them for you?

Comment: I use PAN for usenet client in Ubuntu and it does not appear to offer join or repair. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Hmmm... unfortunately I use only text newsgroups with slrn, but the Pan docs seems to indicate some degree of re-assembling: http://pan.rebelbase.com/manual/html/pan-basic-usage.html#pan-basic-binaries

Comment: Actually I think I have already answered my own question: QuickPar creates the split files and rejoins them with repairs if needed. I think only QuickPar

Comment: Actually I think I have already answered my own question - QuickPar creates the split files and rejoins them with repairs if needed.  I think now only QuickPar can rejoin the parts so I can't go any further with this. Thanks for looking at this.